# datatables: include space in filter string

Tags: datatables

I have an alphanumeric column with strings like "1, 2, 2".
When I type "1, 2, 2" in the search, it seems to be returning all cells with "1," and "2,".
What can I do so the search returns only "1, 2, 2"?

Using Datatables 1.9

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried?

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome Thanks! I've actually figured it out, but can't post the answer so soon after asking. I'll edit my question to provide the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn smart filtering off, bRegex as true treats search string as regular expression:

```
"oSearch": { "bSmart": false, "bRegex": true }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I am not allowed to comment on the previous answer.

In the documetation
[Options (legacy documentation for DataTables v1.9)](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options) says:
"As an object the **"sSearch" parameter must be defined**, but all other parameters are optional."

If you do not define it, you can eventually get the error
"a.oPreviousSearch.sSearch is undefined".

Then add sSearch to bSmart and bRegex parameters:

```
        "oSearch": {
            "bSmart": false, 
            "bRegex": true,
            "sSearch": ""                
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I have tried the above code but the below code worked for me,

```
initComplete: function () {            
            $('.dataTables_filter input').bind('keyup', function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 32) this.value += ' '; });
        }
```

Comment: The snippet you've included seems to be proprietary to a project of yours, it requires jQuery, and doesn't make use of the datatables API. I think you misunderstood the question.